# Javascript regex with 20 chars, more than n numbers in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put two regex's together and haven't figured it out.

I've got the following to match only alphanumeric

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,20}$
```

and i've got the following to match any string with more than 7 numbers in a row

```
^\d{8,20}$
```

How do I put the two together to allow for only 20 alphanumeric characters, with more than 7 numbers in a row

Comment: Do you mean you just want to disallow a string to have 8 or more consecutive digits? Try [`^(?!.*\d{8})[\w-]{1,20}$`](https://regex101.com/r/43ujDR/2).

Comment: Sorry, I meant along the lines of wiktor's comment. I'll try to edit for consistency.

Comment: After the edit, change `?!` to `?=` in wiktor's suggestion. NB: a *digit* would be the better term. A *number* can consist of several digits, a decimal point, ...etc.

Comment: Yes, try [`^(?=.*\d{8})[\w-]{1,20}$`](https://regex101.com/r/43ujDR/3)

Comment: Do you need to put that in one regex? If not, use two separate conditions. The regex will not be very readable after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=.*\d{8})[\w-]{1,20}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/43ujDR/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\d{8})` - after any 0+ chars other than line break chars there must be 8 consecutive digits
- `[\w-]{1,20}` - 1 to 20 word chars (letters, digits or `_`) or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var ss = ["Text_with_1234567", "Text_with_12345678"];
var rx = /^(?=.*\d{8})[\w-]{1,20}$/;
for (var s of ss) {
 console.log(s,"=>",rx.test(s));
}
```

NOTE:

- If you want to make sure these 8 or more digits appear at the start of string, remove `.*` in the lookahead
- If you want to make sure the digits are at the end, use `(?=.*\d{8}$)`.